# Markov chain with absorbing states?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Let's say I have $5$ states (state $2$ to $6$, state $1$ is missing) when time$=0$, and $6$ states (state $1$ to $6$) when time$=1$, and now I want to calculate the transition matrix. Does it mean that the $[1,1]$ element in the matrix $p_{11}=1$, and $p_{12}$ to $p_{16} =0$? But in which case neither row- nor col-sums add up to one. Or can I create a transition matrix which is not square?

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050222/r-add-missing-rows-columns-not-using-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment55855104_34050222

Comment: Do you meant "state 1 to 5" instead of "state 2 to 5"?

Comment: @par yes you're right. I edited it.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: If $p_{11}=1$ and $p_{12}=...=p_{16}=0$, why do the rows not sum to $1$ ?

Comment: @Peter  Thank you. yes you're right they do sums up  to 1.  It is the other case where there are missing columns instead of missing rows.. It's actually a problem I am trying to solve in the stackoverflow link..

Comment: @Natalia I don't think you have given us enough information to work with. What exactly do you want to achieve with this transition matrix? Just the fact that you have $5$ states at $t=0$ and $6$ and $t=1$ definitely does not imply that $p_{11}=1$, and $p_{12}=\dots=p_{16} =0$. It depends on how you want the variable to transition in and out of the new state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your $n\times n$ transition matrix be denoted $M(t)$ (as a function
of time). (i) For all $t\geq0$, $M(t)$ is a right-stochastic matrix
and (ii) for $t<1$, $M(t)$ must be of the form 
$$
M(t)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & M^{\prime}(t)
\end{array}\right]\text{ where }M^{\prime}(t)\text{ is an }(n-1)\times(n-1)\text{ right-stochastic matrix}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you suggest that $p_{11}=1$, and $p_{12}$ to $p_{16} =0$?

Comment: More precisely, $p_{11}(t) = 1$ and  $p_{12}(t) = \cdots = p_{16} = p_{21}(t) = \cdots = p_{61}(t) = 0$ for all $t<1$.